# Calling `new Date(long)` results in "Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970"?

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone, utc

The Java doc describe that the constructor `Date(long date)` constructs a Date object using the given milliseconds time value since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT

When I did `new Date(0)`, the date is Jan 01 **01:00:00** CET 1970

I don't know why it begin with 01h

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's show 1AM because you're an hour ahead of GMT.  A date instance is simply a counter of the number of milliseconds since 00:00:00 1970 *GMT*.  Since your an hour ahead, when the epoch occurred it was actually 1AM your time.

The Date instance simply formats its toString() method to use your system's timezone.  If you want to print out a date using a different zone, use a [DateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) instance.

Comment: hi nichols
if i want to use stardart timezone GMT instead of CET, what's the pattern for HH:mm:ss( i've try HH:mm:ss GMT, it does't work)

thx

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are showing the date in the European timezone (CET) the unix time (the milliseconds you are giving the `Date` object) use GMT.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now()  // Current moment in UTC.
```

## Details

The Answer by Nichols is correct but outdated.

- Your own time zone was an hour ahead of UTC on that date, so midnight in UTC is 1 AM in your zone.
- Nowadays you should be using *java.time* classes such as `Instant` instead of `Date`.

### Avoid legacy classes

Avoid the troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

Among the many problems of the legacy classes was the poor design choice to have the `toString` method dynamically apply the JVM’s current default time zone while generating the string representing the object’s value. A `Date` actually represents a moment in UTC. Avoid awkward class entirely. If necessary, convert between the legacy and modern classes via new methods added to the old classes.

### `Instant` for UTC

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Current moment in UTC.
```

> instant.toString(): 2018-02-11T21:07:02.315283Z

If you want the epoch reference moment used by the *java.time* classes, the first moment of 1970 in UTC, use the predefined constant: `Instant.EPOCH`.

> Instant.EPOCH.toString(): 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

### `OffsetDateTime`

If you need more flexibility, such as generating strings in other formatting, convert the `Instant` object to a `OffsetDateTime` using the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

### ISO 8601

When exchanging date-time values as text, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. They were designed to be easy to parse by machine while also being easy to read by humans across various cultures.

The *java.time* classes use the standard ISO 8601 formats by default when generating/parsing strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

### Time zone, `ZonedDateTime`

If you want to see the same simultaneous moment through the lens of the wall-clock time used by the people of another region, apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` or `CET` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2018-02-11T22:07:02.315283+01:00[Europe/Paris]

Let's look at the *java.time* epoch reference moment through the same time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtEpochParis = Instant.EPOCH.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdtEpochParis.toString(): 1970-01-01T01:00+01:00[Europe/Paris]

Again, for another time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtEpochMontreal = Instant.EPOCH.atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
```

> zdtEpochMontreal.toString(): 1969-12-31T19:00-05:00[America/Montreal]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

With a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complying with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings or java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).